# How do I execute a program from the root workspace when __main__.py is in a lower directory?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python program from a folder but want to do so at the root level<sup>[1]</sup>. My current file structure prevents execution at the root level because `__main__.py` is in the `src` directory.

```
program
 ├───builds
 │   ├───release 0.1.0
 │   │   ├───build
 │   │   │   └───main
 │   │   └───dist
 │   └───release 0.1.1
 ├───meta
 |───src
    └───__main__.py
```

I have tried putting a `__main__.py` in the `program` directory which looks like this:

```py
import src
src.root() # Function that starts the program
```

However, I do not want to go about putting an `__init__.py` file in `src` as it is not a package. Is there any way to go about this in a smarter way that would allow the program to be interpreted at the root level? <sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1]</sup> root level in this scenario is `program`